# jQuery localization calling setdefauls vs datepicker()

Tags: debugging, jquery-ui, localization, datepicker

Can anyone tell me why this happens.

The following code works perfectly, I get the datepicker in German:

```
<input id="foo" type="text"> pick it
<script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#foo" ).datepicker();
        $.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "de" ] );
      });
      </script>
```

But the following code doesn't work (I get the datepicker in Japanese):

```
<input id="foo" type="text"> pick it
<script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#foo" ).datepicker();
        $( "#foo" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "de" ] );
      });
      </script>
```

Here are my include files :

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

Side note. According to the docs http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ it should work. Can anyone reproduce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you your regional code is not recognized by the plugin it sets japanese...
http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/rGpCE/1/

I reproduce it; you can change your code in this way:

> ```
>   $(function() {
>     $("#foo").datepicker();
>     $("#foo").datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional["de"])
>   });
> ```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/rGpCE/2/